# ListView transparency in Android

Tags: java, android

I have set up four tabs that each hold a listview, I have added code in the listview java file to make the lists transparent, however, I have a semi transparent grey box covering 75% of the screen and I cannot figure out why, I have a background on my other listviews and they are completely transparent, but the lists within the tabhost have the grey box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="2dp">
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Tabs extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Draw
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, prem.class);

        // Initialise a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Prem").setIndicator("Prem",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icontabs))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, champ.class);

        // Initialise a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Champ").setIndicator("Champ",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.champ))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, l1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("League 1").setIndicator("L",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.l1))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ll2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("l2").setIndicator("Le",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.l2))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}

public class l1 extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] {"Le"};
        ListView lv = getListView();  
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.le2);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(00000000); 
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, names));
    }

    // Get the item that was clicked
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          if (position == 0) {
```

Comment: The end of your code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout XML file, your tab content (the `FrameLayout`) should be after the tab widget, not before.  It's possible the box you are seeing is the tab widget's background.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```